# Typescript doesn't give me an obvious error with an OnChange method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a project using Typescript/React/MUI. Now I have an onChnage method and thought that Typescript would give me an error regarding the event. But this is not the case. I don't get any error in the console on the contrary (No Issues found). Why is that so?

```
  <TextField
        label="Passwort"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(e) =>
          setPasswort(e.target.value)
        }>
 </TextField>
```

Actually, the function should look like this with TS:

```
  <TextField
        label="Passwort"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HtmlInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
          setPasswort(e.target.value)
        }>
 </TextField>
```

tsconfig.ts:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx"
},
"include": ["src"]
}
```

package.json:

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
```

Comment: Type was inferred automatically, since TextField props are annotated. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html

Comment: it should not give error since the event type is already predefined! so u don't need to define the event type here.